# Como fazer LTRIM() e RTRIM() em Java?

Tags: java, string

Preciso processar umas *strings* em Java. Sei que existe o método `trim()`, mas preciso de um *Left Trim* e de um *Right Trim*.

Como faço isto?

Por enquanto estou percorrendo a *string* com um laço e retirando todos os espaços em branco do começo (até atingir um caractere) ou do final (fazendo um *loop* do final para o começo da *string*).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode utilizar regex:

Right Trim:

```
String texto_filtrado = original.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

Left Trim:

```
String texto_filtrado = original.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

Fonte: http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1418/

Comment: Esse tal de `Regex` parece saber a resposta pra tudo, impressionante.

Comment: `Regex`salva vidas =D

Comment: "O que uma `Regex` e silver tape não resolverem, nada mais resolverá."

Answer (score 9):

Fonte: http://www.fromdev.com/2009/07/playing-with-java-string-trim-basics.html

```
    public static String ltrim(String s) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
            i++;
        }
        return s.substring(i);
    }

    public static String rtrim(String s) {
       int i = s.length()-1;
       while (i > 0 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
            i--;
       }
       return s.substring(0,i+1);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

A biblioteca **Apache Commons** tem métodos na classe `StringUtils` que podem remover caracteres diversos do início ou do final de uma string:

À esquerda:

```
String semEspacosOuTabulacosAEsquerda = StringUtils.stripStart(original, " \t");
```

À direita:

```
String semEspacosOuTabulacoesADireita = StringUtils.stripEnd(original, " \t");
```

Não achei correspondente na **Guava**. :(

De qualquer maneira, com regex você faz isso em uma linha só e sem bibliotecas adicionais (vide a resposta do Maicon).

Answer (score 4):

Soluções baseadas em regex são particularmente lentas e têm desempenho ruim para esse problema. O motivo é que elas foram idealizadas para problemas significativamente mais complicados e complexos do que este, e você acaba usando um canhão para matar uma formiga.

Para projetar a solução ideal em termos de desempenho, nada melhor do que olhar o código-fonte do método `String.trim()`, que [no OpenJDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2852) é assim:

```
public String trim() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

Observe os dois laços `while`. O primeiro laço está pulando os espaços do começo, enquanto que o segundo está descontando os espaços do final. Assim sendo, é possível criar-se uma versão do `rtrim()` e do `ltrim()` ao fazer-se o seguinte:

- Implementar duas versões distantas deste método acima, tirando um laço de uma delas e o outro laço da outra.
- Fazer as modificações necessárias para colocar estes métodos em uma outra classe auxiliar, vez que não é possível adicioná-los diretamente à classe `String`.
- Simplificar o código resultante. Uma vez que cada um dos métodos resultantes vai fazer o `trim` apenas de um lado, é possível simplificar-se ou remover-se algumas expressões que seriam constantes, ou sempre verdadeiras ou sempre falsas que só seriam importantes se o `trim` fosse dos dois lados.

Eis o código resultante:

```
public static String rtrim(String toTrim) {
    char[] val = toTrim.toCharArray();
    int len = val.length;

    while (len > 0 && val[len - 1] <= ' ') {
        len--;
    }
    return len < val.length ? toTrim.substring(0, len) : toTrim;
}

public static String ltrim(String toTrim) {
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = toTrim.toCharArray();
    int len = val.length;

    while (st < len && val[st] <= ' ') {
        st++;
    }
    return st > 0 ? toTrim.substring(st, len) : toTrim;
}
```

[Veja aqui um teste funcionando no Ideone](http://ideone.com/6em2Yn).